# EN_MAXTEXT in Edit and Rich Controls

Tags: c, winapi, controls, edit, richedit

Is it possible to set a user-defined value for notification rather than checking for default EN_MAXTEXT when control has been completely filled?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  User-defined notifications do not exist.

Your (painful) alternative is to use the EN_CHANGE notification to notify you that a user has somehow changed the text and do a manual check to determine if it is full.  (For example, you could check the line length with the EM_LINELENGTH message.) To receive the EN_CHANGE notification, be sure to specify ENM_CHANGE in the mask sent with the EM_SETEVENTMASK message.  (See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761676%28VS.85%29.aspx).)

Your best bet is to make EN_MAXTEXT work for you.